# selecting radio button with highest value

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I need to select a radio button in a list of radio buttons based on their corresponding value.Considering the "dot" at starting to be a radio button, the values against it are extracted from database. I need to select the radio button with highest value among the them.First Column name and second column age.

- Ram     |  25
- Seeta   | 32
- Laxman  | 34

Here when i run in selenium ... the program should select radio button againt laxman since it has the highest age value

[image]

Comment: Could you share HTML of these radioButtons as well for better understanding??

Comment: @saurabh gaur `<td align="center" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">
<input id="ccMain_grdstock_rdselstckpoint_3" type="radio" onclick="javascript:SelectSingleRadiobutton(this.id);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ccMain$grdstock$ctl05$rdselstckpoint\',\'\')', 0)" value="rdselstckpoint" name="ctl00$ccMain$grdstock$ctl05$rdselstckpoint"/>
</td>
<td align="center" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;">                                         4                                     </td>`

Answer (score 0):

This Xpath will help you to get the higher value radio element. I'm using `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`, but you can change it if you need, or to match your html code that was not provided.

```
//input[@type='radio' and not(preceding-sibling::input[@type='radio']/@value>= @value) and not(following-sibling::input[@type='radio']/@value > @value)]
```